# What does "the" specify in the given sentence and what is the head noun?

Tags: grammar

> *The* growth of adults depends on several factors.

What does "the" specify? Does it answer "whose" growth?

What is the head noun here?

Comment: "The" marks the NP as definite. The head of the NP is "growth".

Comment: What is NP here???

Comment: Noun phrase. In your example "the growth of adults" is an NP (noun phrase).

Comment: The growth of adults etc. Adult growth depends on several factors.

Comment: @BillJ, so, "the" signifies growth ? A particular type of growth ?

Comment: "The growth" means the normal growth from infancy to adulthood. It's a common way of speaking used in medicine, etc, but is logical because without "the", it could refer to any kind of growth (getting fatter; a wart or goitre, etc).

Comment: @AryenduKumar The definite article "the" marks it as a particular kind of growth: not just any growth but only that which occurs in adults.